# Hive - Loading into default location of external table

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have an external table created in hive with default location

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `testtable`(
      `id` int, 
      `name` string)
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
     'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
   OUTPUTFORMAT 
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
    LOCATION
    '<hdfs-uri>/hive/warehouse/testtable'
```

Would like to confirm if I can move a text file containing ID/name values from local to HDFS location /hive/warehouse/testtable/test.txt for the external table testtable? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can upload `test.txt` from `local` to the `HDFS` location for external table `testtable` (`<hdfs-uri>/hive/warehouse/testtable`). This will work even if `<hdfs-uri>/hive/warehouse/` is the default `Hive` warehouse directory.

Just to keep in mind - For non-external (called **Hive-managed**) tables, dropping the table will drop its warehouse `HDFS` directory automatically. For **external** table, dropping the table will not drop the `HDFS` directory backing it up, and needs to be deleted as a separate operation.

**Illustration:**

```
Here the Hive warehouse directory is hdfs:///apps/hive/warehouse
```

**Create table**

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `testtable`(
      `id` int, 
      `name` string)
       ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
      STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
        'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
      OUTPUTFORMAT 
        'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
      LOCATION 'hdfs:///apps/hive/warehouse/testtable';
```

**Data in test.txt**

```
1,name-1
2,name-2
3,name-3
```

**Upload data to HDFS**

```
hadoop fs -put test.txt hdfs:///apps/hive/warehouse/testtable
```

**Query table**

```
hive> select * from testtable;
1   name-1
2   name-2
3   name-3
```